# Why do animals get green-eye?

Tags: flash, animals

Multiple sources on the internet (including answers on this site) claim that red-eye is created by light from the flash reflecting on the blood vessels in back of the eye.

So, why do animals like dogs, that I believe also have red blood (I'm not going to injure my dog in order to test this, but I'm pretty sure the blood is red) have green-eye?

Comment: Maybe some sort of vegetation growing on the back of pet's eyes reflecting the light?

Comment: ...and lets not forget Riddick

Comment: +1 for not injuring your dog. (Also, good question :P)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Many animals, including cats and dogs, have a reflective layer of cells at the back of the eye called the *tapetum lucidum* ('the tapestry of clarity'). This reflects the light back through the light-sensitive cells in the retina for a 'second pass', allowing the animal to see better at night.

Comment: You don't have to do photography to notice this green reflective layer; staring into a cat's eye at exactly the right angle will let you see that at naked eye :)

Comment: Yup, headlights are particularly effective at showing them up.

Comment: Nice answer, +1, but no one as yet has explained why the color is green specifically...

Comment: @billare: actually, eyeshine can be white, green, blue, yellow or pink, depending on the angle you view it at.

Answer (score 10):

According to Wikipedia it seems that animals that exhibit this phenomenon (["eyeshine"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tapetum_lucidum)) have an extra layer of tissue within their eyes that cause light to be reflected in a different way.

[image]
<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tapetum_lucidum)</sup>

Comment: Wikipedia has a picture of a cat which dramatically illustrates red eye and "eyeshine" occurring simultaneously.